# Facebook like button goes a few pixels down

Tags: html, css, facebook

I have a little problem with the facebook button layout.

You will see on my site ( http://develop.chaotix.nl ) that the facebook button isn't good positioned.

The same problem as here is explained

[4 pixel offset of "Like" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513009/4-pixel-offset-of-like-button)

Offcourse i tried the solutions but nothing worked (maybe because fb has updated some things?)

I tried everything. Do you people have an solution for me.

The whole code is on the site! I uploaded a text document.

*Please edit my post to correctly English*

Greetings Jochem *student*

Comment: There is absolutely no good reason why you can't move the Facebook container element up a few pixels to compensate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [4 pixel offset of "Like" button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513009/4-pixel-offset-of-like-button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the following into your css it will solve the problem

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment {
    top: -4px;
    }
```

This is a quick fix that will do the job for you.